# submit multiple inputs within a forloop in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, view, controller

My code is to fetch questions of users saved in the database by a foreach loop  and let the admin answer each question and save the answer of each question after checking of validation rules in the database , Here we go :

Model is :

```
public function get_questions(){

  $this->db->select('id,user_name, question, date');
  $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
  $query=$this->db->get('t_questions');
  return $query->result();

}
```

My view is:

```
foreach ($questions as $id => $row) :
            ?> 
        <?php
            
                echo "<h5>".$row->question;
                echo "<br>";
                
                echo "from : ".$row->user_name."</h5>";
                echo date('Y-m-d H:i');
                echo "<br>";
                $q_no='save'.$row->id;
                $ans_no='answer'.$row->id;
                echo  "<h4> Answer:</h4>";
                echo form_open('control_panel'); 
                ?>
                <textarea name='<?php echo 'answer'.$row->id; ?>'  value="set_value('<?php echo 'answer'.$row->id; ?>')" class='form-control' rows='3'> </textarea>
                <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $q_no ; ?>' value='<?php echo $q_no; ?>' />
                <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $ans_no ; ?>' value='<?php echo $ans_no ; ?>' />
                <?php 
                echo form_error($ans_no);
                echo "               
            <div class='form-group'>
                            <div >
                                <label class='checkbox-inline'>
                                
                                <input type='checkbox' name='add_faq' value='yes' />
                                      Adding to FAQ page .
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        

            
          <p>";
          
           ?>
          <input type='submit' name='<?php echo 'save'.$row->id; ?>' value='<?php echo 'save'.$row->id; ?>' class='btn btn-success btn-md'/>
            <?php 
            echo 'answer'.$row->id;
            ?>
            <hr>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and my controller is :

```
 $this->load->model('control_panel');
    $data['questions']=$this->control_panel->get_questions();
    $data['no_of_questions']=count($data['questions']);

      

    if($this->input->post($q_no))
    {
      
      $this->form_validation->set_rules($ans_no,'Answer','required|xss_clean');  
        if($this->form_validation->run())
      {  

      /* code to insert answer in database */
      }

    }
```

of course it did not work with me :
i get errors  :

> > Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: q_no

i do not know how to fix it

I am using  codeigniter as i said in the headline.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller on your `post()` you have a variable called `q_no` you need to set variable that's why not picking it up.

I do not think name="" in input can have php code I think it has to be text only.

Also would be best to add for each in controller and the call it into view.

Please make sure on controller you do some thing like

```
$q_no = $this->input->post('q_no');
$ans_no = $this->input->post('ans_no');
```

Below is how I most likely would do lay out

For each Example On Controller

```
$this->load->model('control_panel');

$data['no_of_questions'] = $this->db->count_all('my_table');

$data['questions'] = array();

$results = $this->control_panel->get_questions();

foreach ($results as $result) {
$data['questions'][] = array(
'question_id' => $result['question_id'],
'q_no' => $result['q_no'],
'ans_no' => $result['ans_no']
);
}

//Then validation


$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('q_no', '', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ans_no', '', 'required');

if ($this->input->post('q_no')) { // Would Not Do It This Way

if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

// Run Database Insert / Update

// Redirect or load same view

} else {


// Run False

$this->load->view('your view', $data);

}

}
```

Example On View

```
<?php foreach ($questions as $question) {?>

<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $question['question_id'];?>"/>
<input type="text" name="q_no" value"<?php echo $question['q_no'];?>"/>
<input type="text"name="a_no" value="<?php echo $question['a_no'];?>"/>

<?php }?>
```

Model

```
public function get_questions(){

  $this->db->select('id,user_name, question, date');
  $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
  $query=$this->db->get('t_questions');
  return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: Firstly ,
`$q_no = $this->input->post('somthing');`
this something is a variable so i wrote it like this : 
`$q_no = $this->input->post('save'.$row->id);`
and it gives me an error :
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
so how can i write this expression ?!
i think the problem is how to pass a variable from the view to the controller !!

Comment: Please check how to use form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html loading variabiles as far as I know name="a_no" and not name="<?php echo 'answer'.$row->id; ?>" name="" has to be text only I think.

Comment: Excuse me , i am a beginner in codeigniter and i am trying to understand what you said .
i do not understand what you edited in the controller
also i do not know why you add many other inputs for id and question in the view

Comment: In your name="" input cannot be any php like you have has to be text. Would recommend watching tutorials and reading user guide

Comment: to explain exactly what i want to do :
it is supposed for users to ask the admin , so their questions are saved t_questions table in the database , then i got them in the view by a foreach loop and i wrote a code under each fetched question for a textbox to let the admin answer each question 
do to validate each answer through the validation rules i differ each answer by the id of the question which is a column in the table t_question
and also i am doing the same for the submit button to differ which submit button is clicked
that is it

Comment: i know that name="" has to be text but in my case the submit input and textarea are within a for loop so the for loop  generates multiple textareas and submit buttons according to number of questions to be answered
so how can it know that the admin answered the fourth question only for example when he clicks submit
by the way i checked the form helper and there is nothing about a variable name of input

Comment: You might need to rethink your code. Try asking at forum.codeigniter.com